# Buzzing Sound in Dash when car off

Tags: noise

2006 SUBARU OUTBACK 2.5L 4WD AUTOMATIC 120,000 MILES
Hello,

Earlier today I cleaned out my car and accidentally hit the parking lights button. Now my battery is dead. However, when I click to parking light off a buzzing (or very fast clicking) starts in the dash to the right of the steering wheel. The sound has been going for more than an hour.

It stops if I turn the parking lights back on, put the key in and turn or hit the honk button. Do you know what it is and is it ok to leave it like that overnight?

For context, the steering wheel is turned very far right, even though the wheels are not (not sure how it ended up that way) and the car currently has an oil leak problem.

Thank you!
Eli

Comment: Disconnect the battery until you can charge it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Did you recharge the battery yet?